# Select all children without selecting parent

Tags: fancytree

I am using fancytree's multi-hierarchy select mode ([selectMode 3](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/SpecSelect)) to select which nodes to remove from the tree. The problem is when all the children are selected - the parent is selected as well, but the user may not want to remove the parent from the hierarchy. I checked the documentation and other Stack Overflow articles but couldn't find a workaround. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the author notes in https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/626 , this situation could be handled by using selectMode: 2.

This mode does not implement any additional logic on its own.
But the click event can be implemented and data.node.visit() can be used to modify the selection state of child nodes.

One complication though is that all child nodes may need to be selected when a parent node is selected. It may help to disable child nodes when the parent is selected.